# is it haram to decompile a .dll assembler to see it's content?

Tags: software

peace be upon you
i'am working with C# programming language,there is an assembler called System.Numerics.dll (it handles big integers and complex numbers).
is it haram to decompile this assembler to see it's source code?.
i want to see the source code because i'am making a similar assembler and i want to see what optimizations can be found there.

Comment: Your question was almost off-topic here. You asked about programming and licenses, which may be fit on Stack Overflow. This forum is all about related to Islam so please rewrite your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft have released the source code under the MIT licence, so it's fine because they have granted permission for you to do exactly that. In fact, here is the source code on Mono

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the software license, is it MIT, Open Source (GNU) or something like that or, closed source proprietary code? Still, not big harm done if you just want to learn by reverse engineering the code and have not intention of committing plagiarism, that is stealing someone's code and presenting it as your own.